# Am I configuring a CodeFirst one-to-many relationship correctly?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm getting errors when I'm trying to add an item that has a one-to-many relationship with another one. I'm not sure why this is, but here's the relevant code:

```
public class ResourcesContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<UserSupervisor> UserSupervisor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserSupervisor>().HasKey(t => t.Id).HasMany(t => t.Users);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(i => i.Id).HasRequired(i => i.Tutor);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Items);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

public class UserSupervisor
{
    private string _emailAddress;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return _emailAddress; }
        set { _emailAddress = value.Replace("@someemail.address", ""); }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int UserNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual UserSupervisor Tutor { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my app.config connection string:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am completely stumped. I have no idea why this is, however. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You can find a similar example here it's more or less what you try to accomplish http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: "I'm getting errors". Why don't you tell which errors? Your question would probably have been answered in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a typo, you try to access a non existing property Items on class User in

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Items);
```

Also since you are using code-first (and assuming you haven't fiddled with the convention settings) you don't have to specify the keys and relationships, but instead let Convention take care of it. By having a property int Id on your entity it will automatically become a primary key for the table.

By having navigation properties on entity classes that belong to the same DbContext you don't have to specify the relationship. So the collection of Users on Tutor, and the Tutor on the User will automatically create relationship. The only thing you need to specify then is that the Tutor is required.

Comment: Whoops, that was left in from some code that wasn't relevant to the example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer though, I am not on my computer at this moment but I will try it tomorrow.